# find text in the string using openedge

Tags: openedge

I need to find word in the string using openedge.
For example:

DEFINE cString AS CHAR INIT "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

I need to find the word after "Excepteur": "sint".
Whats the better way?
Many thanks.
JCA

Answer (score 1):

Use `LOOKUP` to find the word in the string, then `ENTRY` to get the next word. The third parameter on those functions is the delimiter. Use a blank (" ") to divide the string by the spaces between words.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cString AS CHAR INIT "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.".
DEFINE VARIABLE iPos AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cNextWord AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

iPos = LOOKUP("Excepteur", cString, " ").
IF iPos > 0 THEN 
    ASSIGN cNextWord = ENTRY(iPos + 1, cString, " ") NO-ERROR.

MESSAGE cNextWord VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Comment: I hope you do not find the last word in the list.

Comment: In that case, the `NO-ERROR` on the cNextWord assignment keeps an error message from appearing and cNextWord will be blank.

Comment: You will need to search "amet," and not "amet" in that example...